# How does Electrum get transaction input values?

Tags: electrum, electrum-server

https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html#blockchain-transaction-get defines the api for getting txs. Vin values are not included, however. Is it possible to find these without querying for every txid? Is that what Electrum does or is there an easier way?

Comment: This appeared in my close votes list, and people voted for "projects that are not Bitcoin". I don't think that it was intentional from MCCCS to link to ElectrumX which was hijacked by a scam (BSV if i remember correctly). Also, this is a question about the Electrum protocol which applies to Bitcoin too. Therefore i'm voting to leaving this open, @MCCCS could you just clarify that it's about Bitcoin / modify the link ? :)

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about bitcoin, feel free to edit it so that it is more bitcoiny. Also yes, ElectrumX is developed by [a BCH guy](https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx) but it's also what [Electrum uses](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrumx).